# How to open easyui window in a specific position

Tags: window, jquery-easyui

Is it possible to open an easyui window in a specific position, at all? Or just we can place it at center?

If it's possible, how to set the coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

window extends panel, so simply

```
$("#id").window({
  left:10,
  top: 11
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. Use the 'left' and 'top' properties in the data-options. Example:

`<div class="easyui-window toolbar" title="Toolbar" data-options="left:200,top:20" style="width:300px;height:115px;padding:5px;"></div>`